# Child DIV that floats over the text in the parent DIV

Tags: css

I have a parent  with text in it. Inside the parent, I want to float a child  right, but also OVER the top of the text in the parent. Like this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to ask a good question. You need to show your code before we can help you.

Comment: You are required to post a complete but minimal example of your problem markup here. [mcve]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Something like this?

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
  width: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  Some Random Sample Text Here<div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not answer off topic questions. He did not post here the required example markup that reproduces the problem. That is not the purpose of Stack Overflow and answering such questions is a disservice. Not all questions can or should be answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer What you have offered is just a wild guess as to what he needs.